# Can Handsontable beforeRemoveRow be async?

Tags: vuejs2, handsontable

Expectation:
beforeRemoveRow performs an async action (go to database) and then returns false/true. In case of 'false' I expect the row to NOT be removed from the table.

Behavior:
Even when I return 'false' from beforeRemoveRow, the row gets deleted.

Code:
Handsontable with Vue.js

```
<template>
<!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import hot from '@/components/hot/index'
import { url } from '@/constants/api'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      clientAccounts: state => state.clients.clientAccounts,
      token: state => state.auth.token
    })
  },
  data () {
    return {
      hotSettings: {
        beforeRemoveRow: async (index) => {
          const confirmed = confirm('Do you really want to delete the user?')
          if (confirmed) {
            try {
              const result = await this.$store.dispatch({
                type: 'deleteClientAccount',
                id: this.clientAccounts[index].id,
                token: this.token,
              })
              console.log('result', result)
              return true
            } catch (err) {
              return false
            }
          } else {
            return false
          }
        },
        contextMenu: ['remove_row']
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    hot: hot
  }
}
</script>
```

I am wondering if it has to do with the 'async' keyword?
When I remove the 'async' syntax and go with with promise .then it behaves as expected and does not delete the row. However, in this case it fails to perform the async action before deleting the row.

**EDIT**
Handsontable Support answered to this question in their forum:
"the hook is currently running synchronously and only by returning false you're able to cancel the action. 
As I see the last comment suggested to make it work async, which is a good idea. However, currently, Handsontable work only on synchronous calls and it would be impossible to change only one hook."

That said, if anybody found a workaround without hook to prevent removing a row based on database validation, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Since Handsontable is synchronous I had to insert my own function before Handsontable ever gets called.

I'm using the old Handsontable RemoveRow plugin (was removed in 1.11.0), which adds remove buttons next to each row.  Obviously if you're not using the RemoveRow plugin this won't look exactly the same, but maybe it can give you some ideas.

---

Originally, the plugin calls Handsontable to remove the row immediately after the button is pressed:

```js
$(div).on('mouseup', function () {
    instance.alter("remove_row", row); // <---
});
```

I replaced that with a call to my own function:

```js
$(div).on('mouseup', function () {
    requestRemoveRow(instance, row); // <---
});
```

Now in my own function I can make an AJAX request with a callback.  If successful, I'll proceed with the usual Handsontable `alter` call to remove the row:

```js
function requestRemoveRow(handsontable, row) {
    // Disable remove buttons during request to avoid race condition
    $("th.htRemoveRow *").attr("disabled", true);

    $.ajax({
        url: "resource/" + row,
        type: "DELETE"
    })
        .done(function() {
            handsontable.alter("remove_row", row);
        })
        .always(function() {
            // Enable remove buttons after request finishes
            $("th.htRemoveRow *").removeAttr("disabled");
        })
    ;
}
```